# 24bit JPEG converted by ImageMagick to base64 inflates the size

Tags: base64, imagemagick

I have a problem with a few pictures who are JPEG's when I'm converting them through ImageMagick. Below is the string from ImageMagick. The original image was 8MB, ImageMagick compressed it to 1.833MB and the converted base64 string is over 30MB.

```
heb_w2500-00-500-4c-hi.jpg=>/tmp/pic_59974.jpg JPEG 358x640=>84x150 8-bit sRGB 1.833MB 0.100u 0:00.029
```

I've tried different version and they all work except when it's a 24bit JPEG.

Comment: What command did you use?

Comment: Base64 should inflate the size about 40%, or `ceil(size / 3) * 4`. Going from 2MB to 30MB tells me something's wrong with your base64 process. Please show us how you generated the results.